# Python Create New Class in Memory

Tags: python, class, memory, new-operator

I have Class named "Packet".
My Class on github: [Github Packet.py](https://github.com/emrecpp/PacketHandler/blob/main/Packet.py)
Using like this;

```
from Packet import Packet
paket = Packet(0x5)
paket << "123"

paket2 = Packet(255)
print(paket.storage)
print(paket2.storage)
sys.exit(0)
```

Result:

```
bytearray(b'\xff')
bytearray(b'\xff')
```

but as you see in Result, "paket" variable data should be a bytearray(b'\x05') but it's the same as "paket2" variable. Like in a C, How can I create a class in memory so it doesn't affect the changed value to other classes?
Thanks.

Comment: I took a look at your class. `storage` is not an instance variable, it's a class-level variable (sometimes called static variable). It is shared among all instances of your class. The same is true for `_rpos`, `_wpos` and `useNtohl`. To turn them into instance variables, you'll have to define them in your `__init__`, like `self.storage = bytearray()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Paul M.

Answer:

```
def __init__(self)
    self.storage = bytearray()
```